# How to set htaccess working on opensuse for codeigniter project

Tags: htaccess, apache2, codeigniter

I'm trying to have htaccess work on codeigniter project but the module is not working and I don't know how to enable rewrite module. To have read the htaccess. The OS is Opensuse 12.2.

I have this directive in the default-server.conf

```
Alias /safememoirs/ /home/gabriele/Web/safememoirs/

<Directory "/home/gabriele/Web/safememoirs">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I don't understand

A how to enable the module
B Where should I put the .htaccess directive id in the default-server.conf or in the site directory?

Answer (score 1):

To enable use of `.htaccess` files, you need to change the `AllowOverride None` to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Also remember to restart Apache after making changes to the configuration (changes have no effect until you do).  Usually, something like `rcapache2 reload` or `apache2ctl graceful` will do it, but if these don't work, you may need to check the documentation for your configuration.

The `.htaccess` file should be placed in the webroot directory (`/home/gabriele/Web/safememoirs/` in your case).

Also make sure you put:

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

in the `.htaccess` file before any rules.